# Android Retrofit request json prep blocks thread

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I have a big json to prepare which I POST with retrofit.
The callback as my understanding is running in an extra thread to don’t block the UI main thread.

How can I best prepare a large json object before the request without blocking the main thread?

Comment: In Which language should you use for this??

Comment: I am using Android Java

Comment: Can You Use AsyncTask??

Comment: I would say to use first async to prepare the body JSON and then call retrofit/okhttp to execute the request does not sound correct. Not sure if there is like a pre-request interceptor or something like that which runs in a background thread